# Is there a way to hide and show manually inserted page breaks?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, pagelayout

If I create a Notebook that includes multiple pages I know that I can show/hide page breaks by using menu item `File ► Printing Settings ► Show Page Breaks`.  I can manually create my own (non-default) page break by going to menu `Insert ► Page Break`.  But these manual page breaks are not being toggled on and off by the same show/hide page break button.  I would like this control.

Is there a way to control ALL page breaks, including the ones I manually create?  I am including a gif to illustrate that my manually created page break does not disappear.

[image]

Comment: Related: "[How to Add a PageBreak menu by MenuSetup.tr](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/105260/280)."

Comment: Strongly related: "[How can I make an invisible Cell?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113913/280)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name of the menu item `Insert ► Page Break` is a bit misleading. According to the Documentation page for [`ShowPageBreaks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ShowPageBreaks.html), manual page breaking is controlled via the `PageBreakAbove` and `PageBreakBelow` options of `Cell`. This conclusions is further supported from the fact that when you use `Insert ► Page Break` menu item you actually insert the following `Cell` at the insertion point:

```
Cell["", "PageBreak",
 PageBreakBelow->True]
```

But why this `Cell` is displayed even when you set `ShowPageBreaks -> False`? It is because in the "Core.nb" basic stylesheet the following definition is given for the `"PageBreak"` style:

```
Cell[StyleData["PageBreak"],
 Editable->False,
 CellFrame->1,
 CellMargins->{{0, 0}, {1, 1}},
 CellElementSpacings->{"CellMinHeight"->1,
 "ClosedCellHeight"->1},
 CellOpen->False,
 PageBreakBelow->True,
 CellFrameMargins->0,
 CellSize->{Inherited, 2},
 Background->GrayLevel[0.5]]
```

Note that under this you can find more specific definition which is used only in the `"Printout"` style environment and which makes `Cell`s with this style completely invisible when you switch to the "Print Preview..." mode (which by default uses the `"Printout"` style environment):

```
Cell[StyleData["PageBreak", "Printout"],
 CellFrame->0,
 ShowCellBracket->False,
 Background->None]
```

So the conclusion is that what is displayed is NOT a page break but the inserted `Cell` which contains information about it and this display differs substantially from what you see as page breaks when you set `ShowPageBreaks -> True` or use the `File ► Printing Settings ► Show Page Breaks` menu item. So what can be made? First of all, you can set private style definition for the `"PageBreak"` style which will affect your Notebook only. If you did not added any private styles into your Notebook, you can evaluate the following code which will make all `Cell`s with this style completely transparent (if you did, existing private style definitions will be overwritten):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["PageBreak"], FrontEnd`CellFrameStyle -> Opacity[0]]}, 
   StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]]
```

Evaluate this to return to the defaults:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]
```

With this solution the `File ► Printing Settings ► Show Page Breaks` menu item and the `ShowPageBreaks` option will still show/hide the page breaks defined in the `Cell`s added via `Insert ► Page Break` menu item but these `Cell`s themselves will be invisible.

Comment: Awesome!  Yes... I came to same conclusion after looking a little deeper at your first solution.  I decide to zero out the cell margins and graylevel in the stylesheet so that the only thing visible is a little mark for the cell bracket.  Interestingly, when use File ► Printing Settings ► Show Page Breaks it now toggles both types of page breaks ( as far as their visibility on the screen is concerned), so this works.  Thank you for the solution.  It's been bugging me for a while. +100