# How to Add a PageBreak menu by MenuSetup.tr

Tags: front-end, printing, menu

In 1998 there was a discussion on [comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/_51aS4uhwe8) how to add am PageBreak menu to Mathematica.

I used the recipe from there for very long time (in fact, I used Mathematica 4 till almost a year ago).

Now this recipe does not work any longer. I get strange error messages.

Answer (score 9):

On a Linux pc, the relevant file is in a place like this one:

/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.1/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr

To edit the file, one needs administrator rights, i.e. modify it under sudo.

**Since introducing errors can make Mathematica no longer usable, first make a backup copy of the original file before trying to change it!**

I put the following sniplet between the defintions of Palettes and Window:

```
    Menu["Page&Breaks",
     {
          MenuItem["Page Break Above Cell", PageBreakAbove->True, Scope->SelectionCell],
MenuItem["Page Break Below Cell", PageBreakBelow->True, Scope->SelectionCell],
          Delimiter,
          MenuItem["No Break Above Cell",   PageBreakAbove->False, Scope->SelectionCell],
          MenuItem["No Break Below Cell",   PageBreakBelow->False, Scope->SelectionCell]
     }],
```

If you want to indent the new code like everything else in this file, **be careful not to use tab as white spaces!** They will cause errors when Mathamatica starts and *no menu items* will be accessible then!

The result looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An even better version than the one above from me: Paste between the defintions of Palettes and Window:

```
    Menu["Page&Breaks", 
{
    MenuItem["ShowPageBreaks ON ",    ShowPageBreaks->True,      Scope->NotebookDefault],
    MenuItem["ShowPageBreaks OFF",    ShowPageBreaks->False,     Scope->NotebookDefault],
    Delimiter,
    MenuItem["PageBreak Above Cell ", PageBreakAbove->True,      Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["NO   PageBreak Above ", PageBreakAbove->False,     Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["AUTO PageBreak Above ", PageBreakAbove->Automatic, Scope->SelectionCell],
    Delimiter,
    MenuItem["PageBreak Below Cell ", PageBreakBelow->True,      Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["NO   PageBreak Below ", PageBreakBelow->False,     Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["AUTO PageBreak Below ", PageBreakBelow->Automatic, Scope->SelectionCell],
    Delimiter,
    MenuItem["PageBreak Within Cell", PageBreakWithin->True,     Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["NO   PageBreak Within", PageBreakWithin->False,    Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["AUTO PageBreak Within", PageBreakWithin->Automatic, Scope->SelectionCell],
    Delimiter,
    MenuItem["GroupPageBreak Within", GroupPageBreakWithin->True, Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["NO   GroupPBr. Within", GroupPageBreakWithin->False, Scope->SelectionCell],
    MenuItem["AUTO GroupPBr. Within", GroupPageBreakWithin->Automatic, Scope->SelectionCell],
}],
```

This one also gives you access to the other relevant functions around PageBreaks:

[image]