# Create special cell by typing a certain character

Tags: front-end, notebooks

When I type `*`, with the input cursor at the very beginning of a cell, it creates a cell with the `"Item"` style.

Is this feature extensible? Can I define my own special characters which trigger the creation of a special cell?  For example, can we make `'` create a `"Code"` style cell?

Comment: @andre Yes, that's it!

Comment: related: [18406](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18406/5478)

Comment: @Kuba I guess ... but neither of those two are true duplicates in the sense that they're not easy to find ... of course the answers resolve all my problem, especially Carl's.

Comment: @Kuba I would prefer a one-line answer mentioning `StyleKeyMapping` and linking to Carl's description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StyleKeyMapping` does exactly what you need.

It is nicely and concisely explained [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163075/5467).