# How can I make an invisible Cell?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

`Notebook`s have a `Visible` option, but `Cell // Options` doesn't mention any equivalent for `Cell`s. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Select the cell to be "hidden" and use the menu command `Cell | Cell Properties | Open` (for "hidden" cell `Open` should then be unchecked).

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! This problem is that this cell still takes its spaces: `Cell[BoxData["a"], "Input", Background->Hue[.8], CellMargins->0, CellOpen->False, CellFrameMargins -> 0, CellFrame->False, FontSize->1 ShowCellBracket->False
 ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

As [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) correctly notes in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113913/how-can-i-make-an-invisible-cell/113919?noredirect=1#comment309157_113919), with negative `CellMargins` we can make the cell height to be effectively zero:

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["a"], 
  CellElementSpacings -> {"CellMinHeight" -> 0, "ClosedCellHeight" -> 0}, 
  Background -> Hue[.8], CellMargins -> -2, CellOpen -> False, CellFrame -> 0, 
  ShowCellBracket -> False]
```

[image: screenshot]

For the check we can add another `"Input"` cell after our zero-height cell, take a screenshot, then delete our cell programmatically and take a screenshot again, then compare the screenshots. Here are the two screenshots taken with 100% global `Magnification` setting, at the first `im1` only the first two `"Input"` cells are evaluated (the invisible cell is printed), at the second `im2` the Notebook is completely evaluated (as seen from the cell labels; the invisible cell is deleted):

```
im1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ2kx.png"];
im2 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVLJJ.png"];
ImageAssemble[{{im1, im2}}]
```

> [image: two screenshots]

Now compare specifically the distances between the first and the second `"Input"` cells:

```
{i1, i2} = ImageTake[#, {216, 250}, {489, 515}] & /@ {im1, im2}
```

> [image: output]

```
i1 === i2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

They are identical! Indeed we have made a zero-height completely invisible `Cell`!

---

### Original answer

It seems to be impossible to create a `Cell` which takes zero space in the Notebook, but with `CellElementSpacings` you can minimize its height:

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["a"], 
  CellElementSpacings -> {"CellMinHeight" -> 0, "ClosedCellHeight" -> 0}, 
  Background -> Hue[.8], CellMargins -> 0, CellOpen -> False, CellFrame -> 0, 
  ShowCellBracket -> False]
```

[image: screenshot1]

The above screenshot is taken with global `Magnification` set to 150%, the generated `Cell` has height 3 pixels on the screen. If we set `Magnification` to 100%, the height becomes 2 pixels:

[image: screenshot2]

Of course you can make the `Cell` invisible by giving it transparent `Background`:

```
CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["a"], 
  CellElementSpacings -> {"CellMinHeight" -> 0, "ClosedCellHeight" -> 0}, 
  Background -> GrayLevel[0, 0], CellMargins -> 0, CellOpen -> False, CellFrame -> 0, 
  ShowCellBracket -> False]
```

(for some reason `Background -> Opacity[0]` is forbidden but `Background -> GrayLevel[0, 0]` works).

Comment: Such settings of Background are forbidden: "The specified setting for the option Background cannot be used."

Comment: @Rom38 Thank you, I have corrected the code: `Background -> GrayLevel[0, 0]` works.

Comment: You can use negative Margins to get rid of those 2 pixels, e.g.:  `CellMargins -> -2` they do this for `"SlideShowHeader"` style. (Core.nb)

Comment: @Kuba Thank you, it indeed allows to make a zero-height `Cell`, please see the "UPDATE" section.

Comment: Thanks for your fantastic answer !! I was induced to ask this question by the problem of embedding plain text metadata in a notebook, but now, pondering further, I wonder if invisible cells open the Pandora's box, introducing a feature exploitable for security threats.

Comment: @mitochondrial `TaggingRules` seem to be convenient for storing information inside of Notebook, see for example [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5966/280).

Comment: @Alexey Popkov Thanks for the hint. It's just what I'm struggling with since a couple of days. Any advice will be very welcomed !