# How can I clean up a notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells

By cleaning up a notebook, I mean how can I hide all the codes in the notebook so that the end-users can't see it? I saw Eric Schulz's famous interactive calculus textbook, the users can't see the code, and there is no cell brackets on the right hand side of the CDF.

Comment: Please consider adding a reference to the textbook.

Comment: At least closely related: [**113913**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113913/5478), [**14466**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14466/5478), [**680**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/680/5478)

Comment: @Kuba This appears to be directly answered by https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14470/121 therefore I am in favor of marking this as a duplicate.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree, sorry for delay, I should not read via mobile phone because then I forget to answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Update

I have incorporated Kuba's improvement into the code.

Here is how I would do it.

1. In a working notebook (not the target notebook) put the following code.

   ```
   With[{nb = target},
     SetOptions[nb, ShowCellBracket -> False];
     SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> False] & /@ Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Input"];]

   With[{nb = taget},
     SetOptions[nb, ShowCellBracket -> True];
     SetOptions[#, CellOpen -> True] & /@ Cells[nb, CellStyle -> "Input"];]
   ```

   The first code cell will do the clean-up. The second lets you undo it if that becomes necessary.
2. Now in the target notebook evaluate

   ```
   EvaluationNotebook[]
   ```

   This will return a notebook object which will look something like

   $\qquad$[image: nbobj]
3. Cut the notebook object from the target notebook.
4. Select the first token `target` in the working notebook and paste the notebook object over it.
5. Do the same thing for the other `target` token.
6. Delete the `EvaluationNotebook[]` code from the target notebook.
7. Evaluate the ***first*** of the two code cells.

After pasting the notebook object into working notebook, that notebook should look like this:

[image: code]

Comment: Awesome! Works great

Comment: Great solution ...

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility is to modify the notebooks style sheet by defining a new "Screen Environment" that hides cell brackets and closes input cells:

```
SetOptions[
    EvaluationNotebook[],
    StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
        Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb"]],
        Cell[StyleData[All, "Working"], MenuCommandKey->"D"],
        Cell[StyleData[All, "Clean"],
            MenuCommandKey->"C",
            ShowCellBracket->False,
            MenuSortingValue -> 10000
        ],
        Cell[StyleData["Input", "Clean"],
            CellOpen->False]
        },
        StyleDefinitions->"PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"
    ]
]
```

The "Clean" environment hides cell brackets and closes input cells. I also gave it a keyboard short cut, so that using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> switches to the "Clean" environment, and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> switches back to the working environment. Here is an animation:

[image]

Note that I used the keyboard shortcuts to switch at the end of the animation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've decided to to give the bounty to you because it provides a better solution. Thanks again!