# hiding input cells in presentations

Tags: formatting, slideshows

I notice that presentations have the input cells (the ones with code) often hidden.  Specifically in slide shows.  This seems like a pretty basic question, but I can't seem to find out how to do this.  I need to put together a presentation and show a bunch of results.  This is for non-Mathematica users and the code will just make things look unnecessarily confused.  When I double click on an input cell bracket it will hide the output cell.  If I have sections, subsections, etc., I can do the same thing.  I don't know how to hide the complicated code in a presentation.

Comment: Perhaps the answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/194956/45431 will be useful for you.

Comment: See [`Hide Input in a Notebook`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/HideInputInANotebook.html)

Comment: @BobHanlon Ouch - I thought I had tried that.  Obviously not.  Thanks!

Comment: @CarlWoll Nice!  I can't use that for my current situation since there will be some input cells that I want open.  But that will undoubtedly come in handy for future presentations.  Thanks!

Comment: @bbgodfrey More complicated than what I need now.  But it opens a lot of options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I double click on an input cell bracket it will hide the output cell.

Double-click the output cell bracket instead. I mean the one that is highlighted here in yellow, *not* the bracket for the In-Out pair.

[image]

This is what will happen:

[image]