# Hide initialization cell

Tags: visualization, initialization

I would like to load a package at the beginning of a notebook.
So i put these lines inside an initialization cell:

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
<< MyPack`
```

Now i would like to make that cell invisible: idealy, a user that will open that notebook will not see that.

If that is not possible, how can i "close" that cell hiding its content as I can do with other cells?

Comment: If you select the cell bracket on the right, use the menu options Cell->Properties->Open - unselect Open and it should be pretty much invisible

Comment: Possibly related:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113913/how-can-i-make-an-invisible-cell, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14466/is-there-a-way-to-hide-or-toggle-the-visibility-of-code

Comment: Up to now, i have tried only @Jason B method and it looks like it works